# Import 42MB .sql file into WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, magento

I have tried every suggestion I can find without success...edited the php.ini file in WAMP, tried bigdump, tried command line and I cannot import a Magento v1.9 .sql db file in WAMP (latest version).

The .sql is good, because I can import into my live server magento test site without a problem, but it fails every time I try to load to my localhost WAMP setup.

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Is that shows any error?

Comment: nitpick: you're not importing into "wamp". wamp is just a bundle of apache/mysql/php. you're importing into mysql.

Comment: just want to check that you have used "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p magento2 < database.sql "

Right ?

Comment: Yes, I know I am not importing into wamp, and yes I already tried the sql command you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Few options :
Open php.ini file :

```
Locate : post_max_size = 750M
Locate : upload_max_filesize = 750M
Locate : max_execution_time = 5000
Locate : max_input_time = 5000
Locate : memory_limit = 1000M
```

Restart Wampt.

Compress the database, it would decrease the size to a large extent. You can even import Zipped files : i.e abc.sql.zip Or abc.sql.gz

Comment: Already tried editing the ini file with values you suggest and tried a .gz without success

Answer (score 0):

You can use this software to import database file into your local Mysql server

https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog

You can connect this software to your local easily and the select DB. After that you can choose option "restore sql to your DB" by right click menu, choose the file and import. Hope this helps.

If you still get any error, you can paste here.